# Connect H2O with Teradata

Tags: teradata, h2o

I'm trying to find if one can connect to teradata using H2O. Upon reading some of the basic documentation on H2O, i found that H2O has the ability to connect to relational databases provided they supply a JDBC driver.

Link: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html?highlight=jdbc

However, the documentation suggests: "Currently supported SQL databases are MySQL, PostgreSQL, and MariaDB"

So I'm wondering if H2O can connect to other databases like Teradata because they do have a jdbc driver

Link: https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver

-Suhail

Answer (score 1):

The core H2O function `importSqlTable` in `water.jdbc.SQLManager` class is called by both `h2o.import_sql_table` and `h2o.import_sql_select` (H2O R API - must be similar with Python counterparts). After inspecting `importSqlTable` source code I found a problem that will likely prevent you from loading with Teradata due to `SELECT` syntax.

Still I'd suggest trying and reporting in comments on result and error if it fails. When starting H2O server add the following to your command line:

```
  -cp <path_to_h2o_jar>:<path_to_Teradata_jdbc_driver_jar> jdbc.drivers=com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
```

UPDATE:
Use version [Xia (3.22.0.1) - 10/26/2018](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/bcd0be7d9719a4af5dd93171389c5ebbef9cae9b/Changes.md#xia-32201---10262018) or later that fixed JDBC support for Teradata.

Comment: Thank you. We will try this and get back to you with any errors. -Suhail

Comment: support for Teradata is planned for 3.22.0 release: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5780?atlOrigin=eyJpIjoiYzRiYWE0Y2RlZGMxNDI0YmIxMDM0NTI5OWU2MDFjZTMiLCJwIjoiaiJ9